# How do I exclude regions from numeric integration on Mathematica?

Tags: numerical-integration

The part of the equation that is giving me trouble is below:

```
    f[t_,v_]:= Exp[-(1/Log[1-t/v]^2)]*(v-t)
```

I need to integrate this function over the ranges .1 < v < 5 and .1 < T < 1 but I want to exclude singularities which occur when t >= v.  I have tried using the "Exclusions" command but it doesn't seem to work with inequalities.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For this specific example this could also be done as: `NIntegrate[f[t, v], {t, 0.1, 1}, {v, t, 5}]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this with `Exclusions`, as is documented, because `Exclusions` requires the excluded area to be of one fewer dimension than the region of integration.

You can alternatively multiply the integrand by `Boole[t<v]`, to set it to zero whenever $t \geq v$.

Answer (score 6):

```
rgn = ImplicitRegion[0.1 < v < 5 && 0.1 < t < 1 && t < v, {t, v}];

RegionPlot[rgn]
```

[image]

```
f[t_, v_] := Exp[-(1/Log[1 - t/v]^2)]*(v - t)

Plot3D[f[t, v], Element[{t, v}, rgn], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
Integrate[f[t, v], Element[{t, v}, rgn]]

(* 0.0699544 *)
```